# 30-0-30 ACV 8A transformer to 12DCV

Tags: voltage-regulator, transformer, charger

Good Day..
I have a 30ACV 8A transformer. I urgently want to make a 12DCV battery charger from it. What are the components that I should use? Please also help me out with its schematic. Your help would be much appreciated.. THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way .Use a CT rectifier with 2 diodes and about 10 000 microfarads of electrolytic filter cap to make about 42 Volts DC no load .Then use a Buck DC DC convertor to make say 14V